# Adding default values to a list of ordered dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

`python 3.8`

**Given a list of `OrderedDict`s set a default value for all keys missing in all `OrderedList`s from the list. This has to be done preserving the order.**

**Example**

```
def add_defaults(list_of_dicts, default_value):
    #implementation goes here
    pass

first = OrderedDict([('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', 'v3')])
second = OrderedDict([('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k4', 'v4')])
third = OrderedDict([('k2', 'v2'), ('k5', 'v5'), ('k6', 'v6')])
lst=[first, second, third]
print(add_defaults(lst, ''))
```

**Expected Output** (formatted a bit to simplify reading):

```
[OrderedDict([('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', 'v3'), ('k4', ''), ('k5', ''), ('k6', '')]), 
 OrderedDict([('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', ''), ('k4', 'v4'), ('k5', ''), ('k6', '')]), 
 OrderedDict([('k1', ''), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', ''), ('k4', ''), ('k5', 'v5'), ('k6', 'v6')])]
```

**My Implementation**

```
def add_defaults(ordered_dict, default_value):
    all_defaults=OrderedDict({}).fromkeys(
            reduce(lambda k, v: OrderedDict(list(k.items()) + list(v.items())), ordered_dict, {}),
            default_value
    )

    results = [OrderedDict(all_defaults) for _ in range(len(ordered_dict))]

    for result, value in zip(results, ordered_dict):
        result.update(value)

    return results
```

**The problem**

The implementation looks over complicated for such a simple task and does not look like the simplest and pythonic solution. What would be an idiomatic way to implement it?

Comment: Since you are mixing ordered dicts with different keys, it's ambiguous what the order of the keys should be in the end. For example why should `k3` come after `k2`? If we swapped `first` and `second` would the key order in the final dict change?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yes, swapping the first and second changes the order. So the order of the result should follow the order induced by the list.

Comment: Do you start with a list of keys that can be applied to the dicts or do you have to get the list of keys from the dicts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like there's no escaping looking through all the dicts first because you need to know which keys to include. You can do that a little more simply by passing the keys into an `OrderedDict()` in the order seen:

```
default = OrderedDict((k, val) for d in l for k in d.keys())
```

With that you can blend the dictionaries in the list:

```
def add_defaults(l, val):
    default = OrderedDict((k, val) for d in l for k in d.keys())
    return [OrderedDict({**default, **d}) for d in l]

first = OrderedDict([('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', 'v3')])
second = OrderedDict([('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k4', 'v4')])
third = OrderedDict([('k2', 'v2'), ('k5', 'v5'), ('k6', 'v6')])

lst=[first, second, third]

print(add_defaults(lst, ''))
```

Prints:

```
[
 OrderedDict([('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', 'v3'), ('k4', ''), ('k5', ''), ('k6', '')]), 
 OrderedDict([('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', ''), ('k4', 'v4'), ('k5', ''), ('k6', '')]), 
 OrderedDict([('k1', ''), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', ''), ('k4', ''), ('k5', 'v5'), ('k6', 'v6')])
]
```

Comment: I deleted that quickly after I posted it. You weren't supposed to notice.

Comment: Ha @Todd, just happened to be looking when you posted.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is overly complicated. I would just do a single pass to get the keys:

```
allkeys = [k for dct in lst for k in dct]
```

Then to create new ordered dicts, you iterate over the keys and use `.get` with a default value:

```
result = [
    OrderedDict( {k: dct.get(k, '') for k in allkeys } )
    for dct in lst
]
```

So, some general advice, take it or leave it:

---

```
OrderedDict({}).fromkeys(...
```

You can just use `OrderedDict.fromkeys(...`

---

Avoid `reduce` when building new data structures. Python's built-in types aren't designed for the sort of functional approach you might encounter in, say, Scala, where the language was built with this in mind (the implementation of lists as basically [cons lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons#Lists), for example). You've introduced suboptimal behavior here, using concatenation as the reducing operation, because it will result in something like polynomial time. It's also pretty wordy, forcing you to create intermediate lists.

```
 OrderedDict(list(k.items()) + list(v.items()))
```

---

Speaking of the above lambda, don't use python idioms unidiomatically, so `k, v` should refer to dictionary key-value pairs, or something like that. Here, it is two dictionaries, the reduce accumulator and the incoming dict. So even something like:

```
lambda acc, d: OrderedDict(list(acc.items()) + list(d.items()))
```

primes the reader for what to expect better.

Answer (score 3):

`dict` objects also retain the order in which their keys are added. Leveraging this feature, to get the initial list of keys:

```
>>> keys = {**first, **second, **third}.keys()
>>> # or
>>> key_d = {}
>>> for d in (first, second, third):
>>>     key_d.update(d)
>>> keys = key_d.keys()
```

Interestingly, we get the effect of an ordered set with this approach. Take a `dict` and add keys as the set items with dummy values then when you want to know what's in the set, just grab the keys. They'll be in the order added.

The object you get with `dict.keys()` itself is set-like and supports some set operations; however, you lose the order with these operations so `first.keys() | second.keys() | third.keys()` will give us the union of keys, but not in the order they're encountered in the expression from left to right. However, `{**first, **second, **third}.keys()` gives us the union of this "ordered set" in order - same effect (but in order), different syntax.

Once we have the keys, `OrderedDict`s with default values are easy to create.

```
>>> new_first = OrderedDict((k, first.get(k, '')) for k in keys)
>>> new_first
OrderedDict([('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', 'v3'), ('k4', ''), 
             ('k5', ''), ('k6', '')])
```

From the other examples, using a default dictionary to produce new dictionaries with default values is a good idea. This default dictionary doesn't actually have to be an `OrderedDict` itself.

```
>>> default = {k: '' for d in d_list for k in d.keys()}
>>> new_first = {**default, **first}
```

`new_first` now has all the keys in the given order with default values for keys that `first` was missing. `new_first` is already an "ordered dictionary", but if we must convert it specifically to `OrderedDict`:

```
>>> new_first = OrderedDict(new_first)
```

Comment: I think the issue is here is that the sort order of the keys need to come from the order of the lists, not the alphabetical order of the keys. That's why I asked the question in the comments.